# May I apply for Germany blue card visa with a remote work contract?

Tags: germany, blue-card, working

I have received a remote job offer with a six-month trial period from a German company. Can I apply for a BlueCard visa with this contract?

Comment: Do you meet the conditions for a Blue Card https://ec.europa.eu/immigration/blue-card/essential-information_en?

Comment: How much involvement you need from your employer varies but generally speaking that's not something you would do on your own. What kind of contract will your employer offer? If you are not currently in Germany, it would be typical to go through some external HR service provider and to get a local contract in your current location (which would obviously not help).